# how to create array in flutter apis

Tags: flutter, dart

I want submit Selected answers array how can do this.

How to pass selected answer in this array

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your image didn't post correctly. Regardless, you should post code text not code images

Answer (score 0):

Flutter/Dart doesn't have arrays. Use lists instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

In the api-response ,it's always formatted into either **List of Map** or **Map of List**.

List of Map is Like :

```
[

 {
   "name":"ruby",
   "gender":"female"
 },

 {
   "name":"otis",
   "gender":"male"
 },

]
```

And, Map of List is Like :

```
{
    "data": [
        "Professor",
        "Berlin",
        "Tokyo"
    ]
}
```

So to access them you have to use JsonDecode and then look the response and process that.

For **Map** response ....

```
var resMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

For List response (use key after **resMap** with key)...

```
var resMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
var infoList = resMap["data"];
```

## Demo

```
class CatTypeController {
  Future<void> getLeaves() async {
    String url = "https://meowfacts.herokuapp.com/?count=2";

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map rM = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(rM["data"]);
    }
  }
}
```

## Response

[image: ezgif-4-42fcba32ba]

## Output

```
["In ancient Egypt, killing a cat was a crime punishable by death.","The way you treat kittens in the early stages of it's life will render it's personality traits later in life."]
```